# StackOverflowException thrown on x64 systems; works properly on x86

Tags: .net, recursion, 64-bit, stack-overflow

this is just a "to be sure" question here. Are there any known special limitations/bugs on recursion / loops for the x64 systems in .NET 4?

My case is pretty simple - a program runs fine on any x86 system but it crashes with a StackOverflowException on x64 systems (the program includes some xml/mapping code that contains recursions in several places and such).

Currently the only solution for this problem is to call `corflags /32BIT+` on my assembly (and the program starts running correctly). But I was wondering - is there any special cases that are known to cause bugs / issues on x64?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pointers require more memory to represent in x64 (twice as much, in fact). As such, you'll use a lot more memory, and so deep recursion can cause stack overflows on x64 earlier than it would on x86. You might want to try [raising the stack limit](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/rickm/archive/2008/04/22/increasing-the-size-of-your-stack-net-memory-management-part-3.aspx) to mitigate this problem.

Comment: This happened once in a company I worked for... apparently I was the only one in the building that could explain why it happened... those years of C paid off, and they got to ship 64 bit.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the link - both were very helpful. And yes, increasing the stack limit also helped.